# array_combine is return only last value

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have two different `array` for `foreach loop` so i decide to combine them and run in to `foreach loop` together but it's returning only last value of array.

**Array 1: `$FileType`**

```
Array
(
    [0] => image/png
    [1] => image/png
    [2] => image/png
    [3] => image/png
    [4] => image/png
    [5] => image/png
)
```

**Array 2: `$FileName`**

```
Array
(
    [0] => post2.png
    [1] => post5.png
    [2] => post6.png
    [3] => post7.png
    [4] => post8.png
    [5] => post11.png
)
```

**This is my Code:**

```
foreach(array_combine($FileType,$FileName) as $Type => $Name){
                echo $Type .":". $Name;
            }
```

It's return only last Value

**Return:**

```
image/png:post11.png
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how [array_combine](http://php.net/array_combine) works.

You can simply do

```
  foreach($FileName as $id=>$Name)
  {
      echo $FileType[$id] .":". $Name;
  }
```

Assuming both arrays are of same size and same keys

Answer (score 4):

You cannot have the same key multiple times in an array.

Do this instead:

```
foreach (array_combine($FileName, $FileType) as $Name => $Type) {
       echo $Type .":". $Name;
}
```

Comment: I swapped the filename with the filetype since filenames "appear to be" unique. It's easy to miss since variables are similarly named.